# Calculate Latitude and Longitude from Range, Azimuth, and Elevation

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the Latitude and Longitude of a given point provided you know the range, azimuth, and elevation of said point?

Comment: Maybe but this is not the right site to ask the question.

Comment: Take a look here. http://www.satcom.co.uk/article.asp?article=1

Comment: @Ram: I didn't downvote it. I voted to close. I am not the dictionary for StackExchange network so you can gladly go to www.stackexchange.com. The close reason only shows about 4 choices so I voted to close as off-topic. This has nothing to do with C# for starters and you are asking basically a geographical math question which has nothing to do with programming. But you can start next time by losing the piss poor attitude.

Comment: @Dyppl - I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @Ram: It has nothing to do with C# because there is nowhere in the question where you ask about C# (other than the tag which means nothing in this case). It should be tagged as algorithm. The 257 cases you cited had code or referenced a particular framework. You do neither. That's not the right way to ask a question around here. I can't migrate it so you will have to delete it.

Comment: It doesn't need to be migrated at this point. I already got my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at this [link.](http://geostarslib.sourceforge.net/main.html#conv)

Taken off the page.

How do I get the Latitude, Longitude and height of the point indicated by Range, Azimuth, and Elevation?

```
use geoInitLocation() to establish a base location
use geoRae2Efg() to get earth centered coordinates
use geoEfg2Llh() to get Latitude, Longitude, and height.
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help. Looks like some crazy crazy stuff. Would hate to try and write that in C#. Good luch with your project.

Comment: I plan to attempt to PInvoke the dll.  If I am able to determine how it works in more detail I will update my question.

Comment: The link is broken, here is the new one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/geostarslib/